# Contraction of $(2k,2l)$tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors

In picture below ,how to get the equality in red box?

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: This is more or less the definition. What is the definition of $tr$ here?

Comment: It's just exactly what it says. Generally, when you take a contraction, you have to specify the indices you are contracting. This one is just saying: "we are defining the trace of this big tensor to be the contraction of the dual vectors $\omega$ and the vectors $X$ with the appropriate indices of $F$ in order."

Comment: @JohnMa $tr$  is contraction, I have added it above.